# How to manage environment attributes in the Berkshelf way?

Tags: design-patterns, chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf

We'd like to start to adopt Berkshelf (and the Berskshelf way) to favor the use of better development patterns.
We already use "Application Coobook" and "Wrapper Cookbook" patterns but with a large usage of Databags instead of Attributes.
If we wanted to use Attributes, how do we have to configure our applications on an environment level using Berkshelf?
Environments aren't packaged into the cookbooks, they are at chef-repo level and suffer the same limitations as Roles and DataBags do, or not?

Do I have to create multiple attributes files (1 for each enviroment: QA, PROD) in my attributes dir into the cookbook?

Or do I have to create multiple sections (1 for each enviroment: QA, PROD) in the same attribute file?

Or do I have to create multiple environment files (1 for each enviroment: QA.json, PROD.json) under "Enviroments" chef-repo dir in which I define all the attributes that will be overridden?

But in this last case, if I have 100 apps (that is 100 application cookbooks, which is our use case) don't I end up having 2 huge, unmaintainable env files?

Comment: Bosch, do any of the answers work for you? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

With Berkshelf, you still have a chef-repo. You just don't have cookbooks inside it. You should still manage your environment with knife (for now).

You should also consider the data you're storing in environments. If that data should be versioned, it shouldn't be in an environment anyway.